# Opening facebook page and app store using ionic 3 in iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I wanna open my facebook page link using the ionic: It's working in Android using:

```
window.open('fb://page/620967164688741', '_system')
```

and through some tutorials I came to know that in order to open Facebook page, use the:

```
window.open('fb://profile/620967164688741', '_system')
```

But even after doing that, I'm unable to open.

And same goes with open the store, on Android it's working fine but again issue on iOS. Below is the code:

```
let promise = this.market.open('com.teach9.teach9');
```

Can someone correct me where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

How about you check this plugin out for iOS - "inAppBrowser" at "https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/"?

P.S. In iOS you should be able to open any webpage inside the inAppBrowser, Make sure that the target is set as "_blank" instead of "_system".